# Pure CSS Social Media Icons Height Issue and Position Issue

Tags: css

I create a fiddle below. The G in the first icon is not positioned correctly. I need to center it vertically like the other two icons. Also looks like all 3 icons are getting cut off at the bottom.  I have been messing with this far too long and can't not seem to fix either issue.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

html

```
<div class="con">
    <ul>
        <li class="gp"><a href="" title="Google Plus">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li class="fb"><a href="" title="Facebook">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tw"><a href="" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.con {
    position:relative;
    left:180px;
}
.con ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    font:0.875em/1 Arial, sans-serif;
}
.con ul li {
    float:left;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    margin:5px 6px 0 0;
}
.con ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    line-height:36px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.con ul li a:hover, .con ul li a:focus, .con ul li a:active {
    opacity:0.9;
    border-color:#000;
}
.gp a {
    position:relative;
    border-color:#26478d;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    text-indent:10px;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    font:34px Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    line-height:36px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#1e3c7f;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#447aec), to(#1e3c7f));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #447aec, #1e3c7f);
}
.fb a {
    position:relative;
    border-color:#3c5a98;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    text-indent:18px;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:34px;
    line-height:36px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#3c5a98;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.tw a {
    position:relative;
    border-color:#a8eaec;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    text-indent:12px;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    font:bold 34px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    line-height:36px;
    color:#76DDF8;
    background:#daf6f7;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#dbf7f8), to(#88e1e6));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#dbf7f8,#88e1e6);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cc5cQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a style rule :

```
.gp a h2{margin-top:-7px; font:34px georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;}
```

I have surrounded the `.gp a` text within a `<h2>`.
I have modified `.con ul li` a little bit ... like this.

```
{
    float:left;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    margin:5px 6px /*added by me*/10px 0;
}
```

It is now looking better.

[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6T9z/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Admirable what you're trying to do - but you'll need to apply some individual styles to each icon to achieve this.

The use of different font faces, and the fact that the different characters are different heights will make this tricky and need some manual adjustment by eye.

I'd suggest applying a different line-height style to each icon until you get the desired effect. Bear in mind though that each platform / browser may render these fonts slightly differently so it may not be perfect cross browser.

(having just looked on a mac and pc there's a lot of difference in how the g is rendered particularly).

Good luck achieving this.

Comment: @steve...originally this started out as a "simple" test project. Was trying to see if have the icon's without needing the images for page speed and reduced number of server requests vs the aditional html/css was a benefit or not. I appreciate the info on the PC and Mac...will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your icons getting cut at the end, I would just change the height value to a higher value than it is presently. For example, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/cc5cQ/1/

```
.con ul li {
    float:left;
    width:36px;
    height:45px;
    margin:5px 6px 0 0;
}
```

[image]